# Two loops speeds drawing in a Jframe

Tags: java, loops, jframe, drawing

I have a program that requires two classes. The player-Names class, and the Player-Model class. I want the player-Names class to repaint every half second, and the Player-Model class to repaint 60 times per second because i want the movement to be smooth. The problem that i am having is that i want all of this to be done on one J-frame. How would i go about doing this? If you could lead me in the right direction or give me a little example that would be great! Thank you :).

for some reason it wont let me post so i'm going to put in some random code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class PlayerNames extends JFrame {
    static int connectionTimer = 0;
    static int connectionTimer2 = 0;
    static int reconnect = 0;
    static int reconnectValue = 1;
    static int x = 0;
    static int reconnectWait = connectionTimer + reconnectValue;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public graph gg = new graph();
    public graph g = new graph();

    private static GameClient socketClient;
    private GameServer socketServer;

    public static void main(int width, int height) {
        PlayerNames tt = new PlayerNames();
    //  PlayerGraphics t = new PlayerGraphics();
        tt.setSize(width, height);
        if (Game.ServerOwner == 1) {
            tt.setTitle("Server: " + Game.username);
        } else {
            tt.setTitle("Username: " + Game.username);
        }
        tt.setVisible(true);
        tt.getContentPane().add(tt.gg);
        tt.getContentPane().add(tt.g);
        tt.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tt.setResizable(false);
    }
```

Comment: SO is a site that is meant to help other people who have same problem, not only you. You think random code will help some one??

Answer (score 0):

javax.swing.timer is your friend. You need something to draw on and some method that draws on this based on your model (i.e. player data). Then you use the timer to trigger this drawing repeatedly.

Oracle has a tutorial that might help you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html